Bug in how CDC jobs record run_duration in sysjobhistory
Normally SQL Agent job history is recorded in msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory with run_duration in the format DD:MM:HH:SS, -- so for example a value of 105 means 1 minute and 5 seconds.
However the CDC capture job records run_duration differently, with values such as 191 or 497 being very common.
So the question is: How can run_duration be properly interpreted in the case of CDC jobs?
(In case you are wondering why we want to calculate run_duration for CDC, when each CDC cycle lasts exactly 5 seconds, it's because we've encountered a problem where SQL Agent sporadically stops recording history for CDC, and we have to stop and start the CDC capture job to get it to start recording again... so we want to setup an alert to tell us when history isn't being recorded)
EDIT: @SeanGallardy asked for some evidence - here we go:
To repro you just need to set WHERE clause job_id to your own CDC capture job, and the run_date to today, and then stop the job (so that it will restart automatically and you'll start at 0 for the run_duration, making it easier to read):
SELECT message, run_date, run_time, run_duration 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE job_id = 'BBE20D13-4F9E-49F0-8F1E-790C17ED3B97'
AND run_date = '20241030'
order by run_date, run_time, run_duration

Here are some of the first rows from that history, showing two problems.

First, that the run_duration (which should go up in precisely 5 second increments) skips from 56 to 161. The correct change should be from 56 to 101, meaning 1 minute and 1 second. The second problem visible is that there are run_duration values where the right 2 digits are >= 60 --- that should never happen because the field is supposed to be an integer of DD:MM:HH:SS.
I'd note that for all other (non-CDC) jobs, everything works exactly as documented. It's only CDC capture job entries that are misbehaving.
I'd also add that across our fleet we have 15 databases that use CDC, and all 15 of them are displaying this behaviour.

Please update the question with a repro, sample data, queries, etc., to show the problem. Now, as it stands, it's localized to your environment.

Does the example query here not translate the times correctly for you?

Hi @ErikReasonableRatesDarling -- that query works perfectly for all other job history, but not for the CDC capture job history.

The query you show above doesn't perform any date calculation stuff, so it doesn't seem useful here. I happen to have CDC running in a few places, and I can't seem to find where results are incorrect in any of them. Here's an example run.

I also cannot repro this, I get correct times using a correct query for MSDB jobs as @ErikReasonableRatesDarling already pointed out. The fact that you aren't doing any date calculation or manipulation is the bug it seems. https://i.sstatic.net/GPKcyJsQ.png

So it's clear from analysing the run_duration values for CDC that there is a bug in the way run_duration is being recorded for the CDC capture job. This screenshot shows that the minutes column rolls over (correctly) at the 1 minute mark, but then again at the 100 second mark (incorrectly), because they didn't reset the seconds counter as they should have:

It appears that a similar bug also exists for the rollover of minutes into hours -- it is definitely not following the correct pattern.
While I'm sure someone could write some clever code to interpret this properly, it's not worth it for our purposes - our intention is to ignore run_duration for CDC jobs and just check that max(instance_id) is incrementing instead. That is good enough for the alert we are building. [Alternatively we might just schedule the CDC capture job to stop and start once per day]

There is no data given to suggest this. There are no queries, example data, or other items to show the problem and the investigation/outcome. It's just a statement about how there is a bug (with no justifying data) and that somehow this works different than all over agent job reporting. Please add supporting data, queries, and other items, otherwise there is no reason to believe any of this except for localized issues.

Hi @SeanGallardy, I've updated the question with an easy to follow repro. Would appreciate your consideration of repealing your downvote --- never been downvoted before and I gotta say it stung a little. :)

I cannot repro your issue and I have no issues with using proper queries to get proper times. I see no bug here except in your query. Answers which are incorrect should not be upvoted.
